# How do vw and vh units work?

Tags: html, css, browser, viewport-units

I want to know how to calculate the value for `vh` and `vw`. I am designing a website that uses `2vw` and its working perfectly for my text. However, I just guessed. Please tell me how these units work so I can use them in the future. I'd also like to know if they have cross browser support.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`vw` and `vh` are a percentage of the window width and height, respectively: 100vw is 100% of the width, 80vw is 80%, etc.

To calculate the value in pixels, you would just do something like

```
vwToPx = function(vwValue) {
    return $(window).outerWidth()/100*vwValue;
}
```

One thing you should be aware of is that mobile Safari still renders `vh` incorrectly, and anything but the most recent Android browser can't handle either unit.  See [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units).

For more information, you might look at [this article](http://css-tricks.com/the-lengths-of-css/) on csstricks.com.