# CSS Units - What is the difference between vh/vw and %?

Tags: css, viewport-units

I just learned about a new and uncommon CSS unit. `vh` and `vw` measure the percentage of height and width of the viewport respectively.

I looked at this question from Stack Overflow, but it made the units look even more similar.

[How does vw and vh unit works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24876368/how-does-vw-and-vh-unit-works)

The answer specifically says

> vw and vh are a percentage of the window width and height,
>   respectively: 100vw is 100% of the width, 80vw is 80%, etc.

This seems like the exact same as the `%` unit, which is more common.

In Developer Tools, I tried changing the values from vw/vh to % and viceversa and got the same result.

Is there a difference between the two? If not, why were these new units introduced to `CSS3`?

Comment: What vw/vh does is remove the dependency on any parent and allows sizing based on the viewport size.

Comment: Fellow reader, [IanC's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47652830/812102) could well save your day, be sure to check it.

Answer (score 277, accepted):

`100%` can be `100%` of the height of anything. For example, if I have a parent `div` that's `1000px` tall, and a child `div` that is at `100%` height, then that child `div` could theoretically be much taller than the height of the viewport, or much smaller than the height of the viewport, *even though that `div` is set at `100%` height*.

If I instead make that child `div` set at `100vh`, then it'll *only fill up `100%` of the height of the viewport*, and not necessarily the parent `div`.

```css
body,
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.parent {
    background: lightblue;
    float: left;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 50px;
}

.child {
    background: pink;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.viewport-height {
    background: gray;
    float: right;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        100% height
        (parent is 200px)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="viewport-height">
    100vh height
</div>
```

Comment: I had a sidebar that was nested within a bootstrap "row" and I was unable to make it full page size even after setting height: 100%. What worked for me was 100vh

Comment: Check this out to see a visual difference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68306660/6908282

Comment: I think putting both div's inside the parent is a better example. https://jsfiddle.net/2x84tewn/1/

Answer (score 77):

I know the question is very old and @Josh Beam addressed the biggest difference, but there's still another one:

Suppose you have a `<div>`, direct child of `<body>` that you want filling the whole viewport, so you use `width: 100vw; height: 100vh;`. It all works just the same as `width: 100%; height: 100vh;` until you add more content and a vertical scrollbar shows up. Since the `vw` account for the scrollbar as part of the viewport, `width: 100vw;` will be slightly bigger than `width: 100%;`. This little difference ends up adding a horizontal scrollbar (required for the user to see that little extra width) and by consequence, the height would also be a little different on both cases.

That must be taken into consideration when deciding which one to use, even if the parent element size is the same as the document viewport size.

Example:

Using `width:100vw;`:

```css
.fullviewport {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.extracontent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="fullviewport"></div>
<div class="extracontent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Using `width:100%;`:

```css
.fullviewport {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: red;
}

.extracontent {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="fullviewport"></div>
<div class="extracontent"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The CSS `body { overflow: hidden }` will cause the scrollbars not to be displayed.

Comment: @DaveF then you'll not be able to scroll if your page exceeds the viewport and you want vertical scrolling effect. `body { overflow-x: hidden }` should be fine

Answer (score 10):

A percentage of the full viewport width. 10vw will resolve to 10% of the current viewport width, or 48px on a phone that is 480px wide. The difference between % and vw is most similar to the difference between em and rem.

**A % length is relative to local context (containing element) width, while a vw length is relative to the full width of the browser window.**

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your answer and code example, @IanC.  It helped me a lot.  A clarification:  I believe you meant "scrollbar" when you wrote "sidebar."

Here are some related discussions about viewport units counting scrollbars that I also found helpful:

- [Why does vw include the scrollbar as part of the viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551606/why-does-vw-include-the-scrollbar-as-part-of-the-viewport)
- [Using 100vw causes horizontal cropping when vertical scrollbars are present](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46029904/using-100vw-causes-horizontal-cropping-when-vertical-scrollbars-are-present)
- [Prevent 100vw from creating horizontal scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30504010/3340913)
- [Difference between Width:100% and width:100vw?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26939293)

The [W3C spec](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths) for the vw, vh, vmin, vmax units (the "viewport percentage lengths") says "any scrollbars are assumed not to exist".

Apparently Firefox subtracts scrollbar width from 100vw, as @Nolonar's comment at [Difference between Width:100% and width:100vw?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25225716/3340913) observes, citing "Can I Use".

[Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units), perhaps in tension with the spec (?), says all browsers other than Firefox currently "incorrectly" consider 100vw to be the entire page width including the vertical scroll bar.

Answer (score 1):

the vw (view-width) and vh (view-height) units are relational to the view-port size, where 100vw or vh is 100% of the view-port's width/height.

For example, 
if a view-port is 1600px wide, and you specify something as being 2vw, that will be the equivalent of 2% of the view-port width, or 32px.

% unit is always based on the parent element width of the current element

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference that has not necessarily been raised. 100vw includes the width of the scrool bar, while 100% does not include it. It is a small difference, but important when doing design.

Comment: IanC's answer does. "Since the vw account for the scrollbar as part of the viewport, width: 100vw; will be slightly bigger than width: 100%;. "

Answer (score 1):

The difference between % and vw is most similar to the difference between em and rem. A % length is relative to local context (containing element) width, while a vw length is relative to the full width of the browser window.