# Using 100vw causes horizontal cropping when vertical scrollbars are present

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, css-position, viewport

I'm trying to build a website template where the main #content div is 75% the width of the screen, and centered on the page, but I also want to occasionally have sections that span the full width of the viewport. The way I've accomplished this is by applying a class of .full-width on these sections that overrides the margins of the #content div by setting the width to 100vw, as well as some other properties that you can see in the CSS below.

The problem is that, when enough content is on the page that vertical scrollbars appear, the width of the scrollbars is included in the calculation of the viewport width, so content gets hidden behind the scrollbars.

Is there a way around this problem, or a completely different and better way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?

```css
#content {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100vw;
  position: relative;
  left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.full-width img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus.
    Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis.
    Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>

  <div class="full-width">
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/test-image.jpg" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla
      dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit
      lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus.
    Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis.
    Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
</div>
<!-- content -->
```

Comment: I'd actually structure it the other way around - default to 100% width, and add a "container" div around any content that should be 75%. Its the standard way to structure it instead of adding elements to extend outside their containers, and no messing around with trying to allow for scrollbars etc

Comment: I really thought about that, but it seems like bad practice to apply so much markup to the vast majority of the content.

Comment: To be honest, I don't think its any worse than forcing elements to do something they shouldn't by making them extend outside their container, and then having to do calculations in CSS (or worse, JS) to counteract the negative effects :) I understand the reluctance to add more markup, but presumably the containers will have to alternate between 75% and full width, so I can't see how you would have a lot more of one than the other? Also wrapping related content in containers is still somewhat structural so you're not introducing style-only markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the full-width by *default* and when for `#content > p` use `width: 75%` (Now you won't need to set `vw`, the width will *auto-adjust*)

Note that setting *width* 75% for the whole `#content` and then having full-width divs in between makes things needlessly complex - though *hacky* solutions using *negative margins* and *positioning* can be done.

See demo below:

```css
#content > p{
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.full-width {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.full-width img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus.
    Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis.
    Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>

  <div class="full-width">
    <img src="http://toprival.com/temp/test-image.jpg" />
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla
      dapibus. Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit
      lobortis. Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
  </div>

  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque vitae est ut nunc iaculis luctus vitae in risus. Proin mollis facilisis ligula, sed elementum odio consequat quis. Sed at diam urna, vulputate egestas dui. Aenean vehicula fringilla dapibus.
    Fusce aliquet rhoncus leo, vel tempus mi auctor ultricies. Aliquam pulvinar luctus odio, rhoncus tincidunt diam egestas nec. Quisque semper mauris luctus augue rutrum ultrices ut tincidunt elit. Donec ultricies lorem nec justo hendrerit lobortis.
    Curabitur rutrum mattis massa, sit amet faucibus ipsum sodales id. Sed nec orci justo, et vulputate felis. Sed congue, nisl non tincidunt adipiscing, nibh nunc lacinia leo, feugiat feugiat erat neque sit amet est.</p>
</div>
<!-- content -->
```

Comment: @KrisHunt could you please upvote if this answer helped you, thanks!