# How to have a wide break space equal the size of the screen?

Tags: css, wordpress, html, whitespace

I want to make a design effect: after the last line of paragraph A ends, there is a wide space that equal the size of the screen before the next paragraph. This way, the readers can be tricked that A is the last paragraph of the article, while just scrolling a little bit more they will discover that actually it's not.

The problem is the heights of phone screens and computer screens are different, so a fix amount of space is not good. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Take a look at [Viewport Units](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039979/css-units-what-is-the-difference-between-vh-vw-and)

Answer (score 1):

You can learn about relative lengths on  [this](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp) w3Schools lesson. You're probably going to want to make a div that is 100% of the view height in between the paragraphs.