# How to set a line full height of the body

Tags: javascript, html, css

The body of my website doesn't have a specific height so I can not find the exact size of that. I want to show a line from top to down like this:

```css
.lines {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top:0;
}


.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.div2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="lines">

  </div>
  <div class="div1">

  </div>
  <div class="div2">

  </div>

</body>
```

but I can not find the exact height of my body. and `height: 100%;` just fill in a part of the website.

Comment: try to set line-height:100vh;

Comment: It doesn't work 100vh is 100% of the display device not 100% height of the body element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `.lines` to be to [`position: fixed`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#values).

> The element is removed from the normal document flow, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. The element is positioned relative to its initial containing block. Its final position is determined by the values of top, right, bottom, and left.

```css
.lines {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 20px;
  right: 50%;
  top:0;
}


.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}

.div2 {
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="lines"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31039979/css-units-what-is-the-difference-between-vh-vw-and)

I suggest looking in here by using `height: 100vh;`

Answer (score 0):

```css
body{position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px;}
.lines {
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top:0;
}


.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50vh;
}

.div2 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  background-color: blue;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="lines">

  </div>
  <div class="div1">

  </div>
  <div class="div2">

  </div>

</body>
```