# Resize build-results-tab contribution with browser

Tags: reactjs, azure-devops-extensions, azure-devops-services

I have an Azure DevOps extension that adds a custom Build results tab (`ms.vss-build-web.build-results-tab`). Everything is working fine except for the sizing of the component. When the page loads, my component is the correct size (the width of the screen, matching all of the built-in components). However once I resize the browser window, my component is stuck at its original size.

On load:

[image: On load, before resize]

After resizing browser:

[image: After resize]

Calling `SDK.resize()` *seems* to have no impact whatsoever if called *after* the component has  called `SDK.notifyLoadSucceeded()`. If I set a breakpoint, resize the window with the breakpoint hit, and then manually call `SDK.resize()` (before I've notified completion), then the tab resizes to the screen width.

For debugging purposes I've added a button that calls `SDK.resize()`. I've also tried adding a resize event handler to the window, and calling it from there. Neither works.

```js
import * as SDK from "azure-devops-extension-sdk";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import * as React from "react";

export class BuildResultsTab extends React.Component {

    // this is a stripped down version
    // component does some loading/processing between
    // init and notifyLoadSucceeded
    public async componentDidMount() {
        SDK.init({loaded: false, applyTheme: true});
        debugger; // manually resize browser here
        SDK.resize(); // works
        SDK.notifyLoadSucceeded();
        debugger; // resize browser again
        SDK.resize(); // does not seem to work
    }
} 

ReactDOM.render(<BuildResultsTab />, document.getElementById("report-viewer-container"));
```

Note that my component itself is set to fill its container (see CSS below):

```html
<!-- this is reportViewerTab.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <body>
    <div id="report-viewer-container" style="padding: 0; position: absolute; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The problem seems to be with the container itself (the one controlled by Azure DevOps that my component is sandboxed *inside* of). That `iframe` always has a static `height` and `width` set on it which corresponds to the size of the screen when the component first completes loading:

```html
<!-- Note: This is the Azure DevOps controlled container -->
<iframe class="external-content--iframe flex-grow" 
  role="presentation" frameborder="0" 
  src="https://myorg.gallerycdn.vsassets.io/extensions/myorg/report-viewer/0.0.1.42923/1637068395422/report-viewer-tab/reportViewerTab.html" 
  style="height: 565px; width: 871px;"></iframe> <!-- SEE STATIC DIMENSIONS HERE -->
```

[image: Azure DevOps controlled iframe]

I don't set those values, so it must be Azure DevOps adding them (I assume as part of the `resize` call). The same thing happens in mobile; loading the tab looks great but if I then switch to landscape view everything resizes except my tab.

Am I missing something? Is there a way to get my tab's container to resize with the rest of the window? It's not a big deal, but it certainly is annoying.

I am using the `azure-devops-ui` v2.167.21 (React components) package alongside `azure-devops-extension-sdk` v2.0.11.

Here's a snippet of my extension manifest, in case it matters:

```json
{
    "manifestVersion": 1,
    // snip
    "targets": [{
       "id": "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services"
    }],    
    "scopes": [ "vso.build" ],
    // snip
    "contributions": [
        {
            "id": "report-viewer-tab",
            "type": "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-tab",
            "description": "Report Viewer Tab",
            "targets": [
                "ms.vss-build-web.build-results-view"
            ],
            "properties": {
                "name": "Report Viewer",
                "title":"Reports",
                "uri": "report-viewer-tab/reportViewerTab.html",
                "dynamic": true,
                "supportsTasks": ["817c6dfe-0ecf-494b-9b94-0b13bdb7d613"],
                "supportsMobile": true
            },          
            "includes": [
                "ms.vss-releaseManagement-web.release-service-data-external"
            ]
        }        
    ],
    "files": [
       // snip... appropriate paths are here
    ]
}
```

I've also tried setting `contributions[0].properties.width` to `"100%"` based on some examples found in a Github search but that didn't seem to do anything. That's also where the `dynamic: true` came from and I admit I have absolutely no clue what that is supposed to do--documentation on this stuff is fairly lacking.

Comment: I have no idea about Azure Cloud, but I had a similar issue and ended up solving it by defining the component size in vh and vw units instead of pixels or relative %. Related to that matter check this answer _https://stackoverflow.com/a/24876734/16091749_

Comment: I guess its problem with your component. In reportViewerTab.html, please try to use relative instead of absolute.

Comment: I tried vw/vh, relative, absolute and even removed all styling. It turns out with no styles my component fills the iframe. But... It's not my component that has the issue. It's the iframe that azure devops is hosting it inside of. All of those combinations and the iframe still ends up with static width/height that correspond to the initial screen size. Even if I force my component to have no content at all, the iframe ends up with those (or similar) dimensions.